# How to set custom preview image and description when sharing a ReactJS app page?

Tags: reactjs, meta-tags, react-helmet

I have a ReactJS app, and I want to customize the preview image and description when sharing a specific page. Currently, when I share the link to the page, it uses the default preview specified in the index.html file. However, I would like to dynamically set the preview image and description based on the content of the page.

In my ProductDetails.js component, I have the following code:
....
`const formattedProductImage = singleProduct && singleProduct.pricing?.price && ( singleProduct && singleProduct.imageUrls ) const formattedProductDescription = singleProduct && singleProduct.pricing?.price && ( singleProduct && singleProduct.description )` 
...

How can I modify this code or add additional code to set the preview image and description for sharing this specific page? I want to use the formattedProductImage and formattedProductDescription variables as the custom preview when sharing the link.

I would appreciate any guidance or code examples on how to achieve this. Thank you!

Comment: You can use `skeleton` components from different react styling libs (e.g. MUI, AntD). It helps to show the preview of data that we want to share to show the users.